# Error: "The module cannot be loaded because only single file assemblies are supported" in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

Despite having a several years background in .NET backend, I'm a newbie in cross-platforms, hence in .NET Core.
I'm struggling the below error during runtime of the component developed in .NET Core 3.1 framework which is a worker service (introduced in .NET Core 3.x).

Any ideas folks?

Important: This .netmodule file is already being utilized in our current backend in .NET environment bundled with another .dll assembly file(s). I know that most of the .NET 3rd party libraries are NOT compatible with .NET Core area. However, I'm not sure whether there's a hidden catch on the issue; since when I google'd the error message, I could not find any exact match.

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'dcpssacs.netmodule'. The module cannot be loaded because only single file assemblies are supported. (0x8013101E)
File name: 'dcpssacs.netmodule'
   at DDSMessageReceiver.Core.GenericSimplicityLayer.DefaultSettings(BaseModel& baseModel)
   at DDSMessageReceiver.Worker.InitializeModules() in C:\Triodor_Workspace\T4CNext\DDSMessageReceiver\DDSMessageReceiver\Worker.cs:line 83
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__139_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Comment: The error message is explicit, CoreCLR does not support assemblies that are built from multiple .netmodules and linked with al.exe.  Already quite obscure in .NETFramework, this is not a practical problem.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the comment. as per my understanding, that means, we are unable to go on with .NET Core, unless we have the source codes of the 3rd party .dll.